# I keep getting this error 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0"

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Keep getting this error:

> 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

Can someone help me edit this code?

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertOKTitle, style:.destructive, handler: { alertAction in
            self.okButtonPressed()
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertCancelTitle, style:.cancel, handler:{ alertAction in
            self.cancelButtonPressed()
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertRemindLaterTitle, style:.default, handler: { alertAction in
            self.remindLaterButtonPressed()
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let controller = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController

        controller?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = alertTitle
        alert.message = alertMessage
        alert.addButton(withTitle: alertCancelTitle)
        alert.addButton(withTitle: alertRemindLaterTitle)
        alert.addButton(withTitle: alertOKTitle)
        alert.delegate = self
        alert.show()
    }


}

internal func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView , clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int){

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        cancelButtonPressed()
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        remindLaterButtonPressed()
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        okButtonPressed()
    }

    alertView.dismiss(withClickedButtonIndex: buttonIndex, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you want the edits to accomplish...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, `UIAlertView` was deprecated as of iOS 9.0. `UIAlertController` was added in iOS 8.0. Your code is correctly choosing to use `UIAlertController` under iOS 8.0 or later.

The problem is that your code tries to use `UIAlertView` for anything earlier than iOS 8.0. But your app's Deployment Target is not set for iOS 7 or earlier. Therefore the compiler is telling you that `UIAlertView` is deprecated.

Since you are not actually going to be supporting anything earlier than iOS 8.0, there is no need for the `if #available(iOS 8.0, *)` or for `UIAlertView`. Just write your code using `UIAlertController` and don't worry about `UIAlertView`.

All of the code you posted can be reduced to just the `UIAlertController` part:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertOKTitle, style:.destructive, handler: { alertAction in
    self.okButtonPressed()
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertCancelTitle, style:.cancel, handler:{ alertAction in
    self.cancelButtonPressed()
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertRemindLaterTitle, style:.default, handler: { alertAction in
    self.remindLaterButtonPressed()
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let controller = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController

controller?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```